# Specifying allowed values for a method parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Like in title - for example I have a method `DrawMe(what)` and I want to allow to run this method when `what` argument is equal to one of this values: `{"house", "garden", "cat", "dog"}` - and if not then this method should be stopped and an error should be printed. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using symbols, not strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Draw
  ALLOWED = %w[house garden cat dog]
  def self.me(what)
    raise ArgumentError, "Unknown drawable '#{what}'" unless ALLOWED.include?(what)
    # Otherwise, carry on!
    puts "I'm going to draw a #{what}!"
  end
end

Draw.me('garden') #=> I'm going to draw a garden!
Draw.me('cat'   ) #=> I'm going to draw a cat!
Draw.me('morals') #=> RuntimeError: Unknown drawable 'morals'
```

However, note that *most of the time* you should not be ensuring that developers passed the right type of value into your method. Your method will raise its own error if something explodes as a result of misuse; it's a waste of your time and the computer's time to attempt to check and catch errors like this.

**Edit**: If you need to use this frequently, you could monkeypatch it in everywhere:

```
class Object
  def ensure_in( enumerable )
    unless enumerable.include?( self )
      raise ArgumentError, "#{self} must be one of #{enumerable}"
    end
  end
end

def me(what)
  what.ensure_in( ALLOWED )
  # Go ahead
end
```

Comment: thanks! I thought about something like that, but is there some other(simpler/shorter?) way to do such a think in ruby/rails? EDIT: thanks for the suggestion too, but I'm currently developing my first ruby gem and I really want that feature in it ;)

Comment: Something shorter than `raise '...' unless FOO.include?(bar)`? Like what? How could that be much shorter? You have to tell it to fail, you have to tell it what values are legal, and you have to tell if what value to check. You can omit the nice message, if you like.

Comment: I just thought that maybe this feature (run method only with specified values) is implemented in some buit-in method in ruby/rails which I didn't know - thanks again anyway ;)

Comment: Well, if you are hell-bent on doing this often, you could make a method for it. See my edit. (Or you could add `Enumerable#ensure_includes`, or you could add `Kernel#ensure_exists(object,enumerable)`.)

Comment: Raising an ArgumentError might be better than RuntimeError. And checking the arguments (rather than leaving it to something down the chain) can make debugging significantly easier; I'm sure you've spent some time puzzling over a Rails stack trace trying to figure out what went wrong a little more interface strictness would tell you right away.

Comment: Great point about the error; updated. (I don't use Rails, but I understand your argument even if I don't agree with it. Anyhow, I did intentionally write and italicize _"most of the time"_; certain exceptions are wholly reasonable.)

Comment: I did notice that you were careful to qualify your statement but I've wasted too much time dealing with stack traces (especially when cause and effect are separated and not even in the same call chain) to let it by without saying something. The problem is more pronounced in complicated frameworks/libraries (such as Rails) than in simpler ones.